# using linq to entity to get records based on related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a entity of type Campaign that I would like to find all Orders that have a campaign of that same entity. I am stumped on how to do what should probably be a pretty simple query.
This is logically what the query should be but it is not valid.

```
var myCampaign  = db.Campaigns.Find(15); //15 being the Id of the campaign I want to use for comparison
var orders= db.Orders.Where(a=>a.Campaigns.Equals(myCampaign)).ToList();
```

Comment: You should be able to add a navigation property in `Campaign` class. With that getting what you need would be easy, something like `var orders = myCompaign.Orders;`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that there is a navigation property like that already

Comment: Why don't you use it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might try the `Any` operator like below (assumes Campaign field/property name "CampaignId"):

```
var campaignId = 15;
db.Orders.Where(o => o.Campaigns.Any(c => c.CampaignId == campaignId)).ToList();
```